# Construction of sequence of smooth functions that don't converge to a smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Given $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by:

$$f(x)= 
\begin{cases} 
2x & x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]\\
-2x+2 & x\in[\frac{1}{2},1]
\end{cases}
$$

How can I construct a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions that are always smaller but converge to $f$? Is there a systematic way to do it?

I'm trying to have all the details for the proof that the space of $C^1$ functions is not a Banach space in the uniform convergence norm.

Comment: How about a Fourier series?

Comment: The example I saw on class the professor just drew some curves that looked like parabolas, so they were all below f(x)

He asked us to come up with a formula for that, but yeah a Fourier Series might work

Comment: In that case your professor is probably drawing hyperbolas. You can write down a formula for a sequence of hyperbolas in a natural way such that they approach their natural asymptote in a limit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the family of hyperbolas

$$(y-1)^2 - (2x-1)^2 = r^2$$

In the limit as $r\to 0$, this approaches the mutual asymptotes of all of the hyperbolas

$$|y-1| = |2x-1|$$

So consider the sequence of functions

$$f_n(x) = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+(2x-1)^2}$$

I will leave the proof of smoothness on the interval $[0,1]$ to you.